# I need to edit video frame by frame, and also convert these frames into video again

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, video-editing

I need to edit the video frame by frame. If I'm extracting video in frames (using image approach), app is crashing due to memory.

3 minutes video is exceeding the limit of 1GB.

```
func getAllFrames() -> [UIImage] {


    let duration: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)

    self.generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    self.generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    self.images = []
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    for index: Int in 0 ..< Int(duration) * 24 {

        let time = NSValue(time: CMTime(seconds: Double(index), preferredTimescale: 60))
        imageTime.append(time)
    }

    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: imageTime, completionHandler: { (_, cgImage, _, _, _) in
        if let cgImage = cgImage {

            self.images.append(UIImage(cgImage: cgImage))

            print("Image size is ", UIImage(cgImage: cgImage).getImageSize())
        }
    })
    self.generator = nil
    return self.images
}
```

Comment: Con you show us your research on it and what you have in term of code ? It would be much more helpful to provide you a good answer !

Comment: Now I have uploaded the code

Comment: What kinds of edits do you want to perform?

Comment: I need to draw something on that frame